# Sql Server 2008 not ignoring a noise word in a fulltext phrasal query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, stop-words

Lets assume we have a table with a fulltext field on it. This field is called `text`. The content of the table would be:

```
car wash
car and wash
```

The word `and` is in my `stoplist`

Now, I will query this table using this sql:

```
select * from mytable
where contains(text, '"car wash"')
```

This query only returns the `car wash` row and not the `car and wash` row. By assuming that the word `and` is a stop word, why is not Sql returning the `car and wash` row?

I know I am doing a phrasal search (using ""). That is exactly what I need, but I think that Sql should ignore words in the stop list and that is not what is happening. It is driving me crazy.

My understand is that when FT algorithm finds a phrase like `car and wash` it will index only `car` and `wash`. Is this true?

Also when I query the `ft_parser` it says what I expected it to say:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"car and wash"', 1033, 5, 0)

    special_term    display_term    
    Exact Match         car 
    Noise Word          and 
    Exact Match         wash
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this article:
[stopwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

> Although fts ignores the inclusion of stopwords, the full-text index does take into account their position

after fts ignores "and" word, "car" and "wash" positions will be 1 and 3. So it can't be found.

I suggest another term instead. Maybe you would like to use something like 'car AND wash', or other term. That depends on business logic